# Diawi- Only possible from safari

Tags: ios, iphone, safari, diawi

I am getting an error on one of device that "Only possible from Safari" while i am opening the diawi generated link in safari. i have 12 devices registered in my developer account. Diawi generated link is working fine in 11 out of 12 devices.I have cross checked UDID, povisioning profile, build everything that is possible to resolve this issue. Enclosing a screenshot-
  [Image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5fF6.jpg)

Comment: Where is your screenshot?

Comment: @Daniel check the link

Comment: if you didnt login/register in diawi, then you can do 10 installations per app. Refer-https://www.diawi.com/features-services

Comment: You can use AppBox,A mac application that uses your dropbox account to distribute you ad-hoc and enterprice apps, if you want to install form any other browser https://github.com/vineetchoudhary/AppBox-iOSAppsWirelessInstallation/releases

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using **IOS 13+**, tap the '**aA**' button on the **left** of the address bar and select **request mobile website** option.

If not please check following things,

1. Open **Settings**
2. Navigate to **Safari** > **Advanced**
3. Enable **Web Inspector**
4. Enable **JavaScript**
5. Switch back to Safari and load a web page

Answer (score 7):

You need to run the page in mobile mode.
for iOS 13+, Tap the AA (left-hand side of Diawi address) and Request to Mobile Website.

Answer (score 3):

You might be getting this error due to **Javascript** being disabled in **Safari**.

Navigate to **Settings** > **Safari** > **Advanced**

If Javascript is disabled , Enable that and reload the link in Safari.

else try disabling and enabling javascript.